# SVG Font Inkscape two not connected path as one glyph

Tags: inkscape

Can anyone tell me, why I can't use not connected paths as one glyph? e.g. I selected 2 stars and wanted to make them as one glyphe, but Inkscape just use the first selected one.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the `combine` operation (`CTRL`-`K`) which will make a single path out of two. Should do what you expect if they are not overlapping, else try the `path union` (`CTRL`-`+`)